# Unexpected behavior when using websockets

Tags: javascript, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I want to create a basic chat system which allows the user to attach a `file` to a given message.

This is a problem with `web sockets` because it is very difficult to send a `file` through them. unless you want to convert it to binary data. That wont work for me however because I want to be able to interact with the files on the server, and since i have multiple file types (different images, videos and gifs), I cant just decode the binary.

Here is my code:

Where I make the `request` to upload the message:

```
// this.state._new_message : {
//     _message_type_id:int,
//     _message:string || file,
//     _user_id:int,
//     _conversation_id:int
// } -> this is what a _new_message object looks like.

let fd = new FormData()

if(this.state._new_message._message_type_id !== 1){
    fd.append("file", this.state._new_message._message)
}

fd.append("message", JSON.stringify(this.state._new_message))

Axios.post(API_URL+"/api/chat/send_message", fd)
.then(res => res.data)
.then(res => {
    this.socket.emit("message", res._message)
})
```

Where I handle the `request`:

```
def send_message(self, request):
    data = request.form["message"]
    data = json.loads(data)
    if data["_message_type_id"] != 1:
        data["_message"] = "Loading Message. Please Wait."

    query = fdb.prepare(data, "_messages") # Converts the data dict to a query string

    fdb.create(query["query_string"], query["query_params"]) # Interacts with Database
    _message = fdb.read("""SELECT * FROM _messages WHERE _id = LAST_INSERT_ID()""", (), False)

    if data["_message_type_id"] != 1:
        file = request.files["file"]
        # OpenCV magic... #
        path = "path/to/file"
        file.save(path)
            
        fdb.update("""UPDATE _messages SET _message = %s WHERE _id = %s""", (url_path, _message["_id"])) # Interacts with Database
        url_path = "url/path/to/file"
        _message["_message"] = url_path # If message is not text, set it to be the path to the file instead
        
        
    return jsonify({
        "_message" : _message
    })
```

This is where I listen for the `event` (`server`):

```
@socket.on("message")
def handleMessage(msg):
    print(msg)
    send(msg, broadcast=True)
    return None
```

This is where I listen for the `event` (`client`):

```
this.socket.on("message", data => {
    if(data == null || data._message_type_id == undefined) return
    if(this.props.chat.messages.messages !== null)
        if(this.props.chat.messages.messages.filter(message => parseInt(message._id) === parseInt(data._id)).length > 0) return
    this.props.addMessage(data)
})
```

From this code, you'd expect to send a message through `HTTP`, that message to be processed and sent back through `HTTP`, then the response to be sent to the `server` through the `socket`, and the `socket` to then `send` that message to all the `clients` which are listening to that `socket`. But it doens't work that way. Some times it does, other times it doesn't.

One thing I can confirm is that the messages are saved to the database and file system 100% of the time. I also always get a response from the `HTTP request`, but when I `emit` the `event` from the `client` and `print` them message in the server, I some times get `None` or the previous message logged to the console.

So when that message is sent to the `client`, my "`error catching block`" will see that its either `undefined` or already exists, so it will `return` without adding it (because it shouldnt add it of course).

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Do I have a wrong idea about something? Or is there wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

After a bit of time analyzing my code, I noticed that I do not `execute` the following two `queries` in the same `transaction`:

```
fdb.create(query["query_string"], query["query_params"]) # Interacts with Database
_message = fdb.read("""SELECT * FROM _messages WHERE _id = LAST_INSERT_ID()""", (), False)
```

The `fdb` extension I developed is basically a high level abstraction of `sqlalchemy` which has a very loose transaction management system (auto open/close). So I had to implicitly tell it to not close the transaction until it executes both queries.

As a result, I always get the latest insert, and not the insert which occurred beforehand (as was the case before I updated my code).

Goes to show you that abstraction of code isn't always a good idea if you don't think of all the use cases in advanced.