# SQLAlchemy, Flask and cross-contamination?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have taken over a flask app, but it does not use the flask-sqlalchemy plugin. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how it's set up.

It has a `database.py` file.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session, Session


_session_factory = None
_scoped_session_cls = None
_db_session: Session = None


def _get_session_factory():
    global _session_factory
    if _session_factory is None:
        _session_factory = sessionmaker(
            bind=create_engine(CONNECTION_URL)
        )
    return _session_factory


def new_session():
    session_factory = _get_session_factory()
    return session_factory()


def new_scoped_session():
    global _scoped_session_cls
    if _scoped_session_cls is None:
        session_factory = _get_session_factory()
        if not session_factory:
            return
        _scoped_session_cls = scoped_session(session_factory)
    return _scoped_session_cls()


def init_session():
    global _db_session

    if _db_session is not None:
        log.warning("already init")
    else:
        _db_session = new_scoped_session()
    return _db_session


def get_session():
    return _db_session
```

We we start up the flask app, it calls `database.init_session()` and then anytime we want to use the database it calls `database.get_session()`.

Is this a correct/safe way to interact with the database? What happens if there are two requests being processed at the same time by different threads? Will this result in cross-contamination with both using the same session

Comment: Different threads will give different sessions, but you could possibly make it safer using a [Custom Scope](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes) for your `scoped_session`, and bind it to you web request.

Comment: okay so this code isn't broken and would work as expected. Since each request is processed in a thread without any threads/multiprocessing within each individual request. thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?  What is it that you don't understand (after reading the relevant [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions)?

Comment: Basically I'm not sure if there can be contamination across different unique requests if they are processed by the same thread? And in general, is the code there, correct and will work

Comment: Because I still haven't gotten an answer I'm happy with and although the code works, I don't like the fact I don't fully know if it's correct.

Comment: Outside of the file, but somewhere you should be calling `session.Remove` once the request has been handled.

Comment: Refer to my answer to my question that was caused by similar implementation of `sqlalchemy`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63989043/7929036

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain what is happening in your code, let's first dive into how `sqlalchemy` connects to your database:

#### 1. Creating [an Engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html):

- Connection to your database is stored in an [engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html).

  - At minimum, you must supply a [connection URI / database URL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#database-urls)
  - Connection engine is quite powerful, see [connection parameters](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api) for more.
- An engine is created with [`create_engine()` function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api).

  - It is advised to re-use the same engine, since each engine will reserve database connections (for a reserved [connection pool](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html)).
- Connect to your database with [`engine.connect()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#basic-usage) -> this will open one connection to your database.

  - [Connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#connection-engine-api) are not thread safe.

**At this point, you can connect with your database directly:**

```py
engine = create_engine(...)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(...)
```

Do note, objects created/altered within the context of this connection are not guaranteed to share state outside of the connection context, until the transaction is completed / connection closed.

To perform more complex queries (ex: mix of select and insert), you will want to use a Session.

#### 2. Opening a [session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#session-basics):

- A session is created from an `engine` object:

  ```
  with Session(engine) as session:
      ...
  ```
- More often, a session will be created by the [`sessionmaker()` factory method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#using-a-sessionmaker):

  ```py
  Session = sessionmaker(engine)
  ```
- Sessions can be used across a project, and are often how objects are mapped to a shared global state.

  - Note: sessions [cannot be shared across threads](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe-is-asyncsession-safe-to-share-in-concurrent-tasks).

#### 3. Examining the code above:

The oversimplified purpose of the code above is to create a session object, via `get_session()`.

Initially, this will return `None`, since this is the value of `_db_session`.

Therefore, you must call `init_session()` which will create the various objects needed to return a session from `get_session()`.

**Here's what happens within `init_session()`**:

1. Calls `new_scoped_session()` which will return a `session_factory`
2. Calls `_get_session_factory()` which will ***create*** the `session_factory` -> note how it creates an `engine` from the `CONNECTION_URL`
3. Calls `scoped_session(session_factory)` which creates a [scoped session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes) and assigned to `_scoped_session_cls`.
   ***Note:** This performs very similarly to a regular session, except is even more isolated (and safe).*

Lots of the complexity is related to the caching of state. Essentially, the code is doing the following:

```py
_session_factory = sessionmaker(
    bind=create_engine(CONNECTION_URL)
)

_scoped_session_cls = scoped_session(session_factory)

def new_session():
    return _scoped_session_cls()
```

---

I hope this was helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the great  explanation. So if I call `db_client.get_session()` during a Flask request, and either `commit()` or in the case of a error `rollback()` is there any chance of cross contaminations between threads? or between different requests handled by the same threads?

Comment: In your case, all requests will be using the same session. Since no `scope` is explicitly provided to `scoped_session`. So any object in 1 session will be shared throughout. Unless you call `db_client.new_session()`, in which case, an isolated session will be returned (each time). @user7692855

Comment: Is scoped_session not scoped by thread?

Comment: It's scoped by `request-id` – so yes, it is. It is unsafe to share across threads. @user7692855

Comment: Unfortunately I'm even more confused now - `In your case, all requests will be using the same session`  and `It's scoped by request-id`  Is the issue we're only calling `scoped-session` once and assigning it to the class?

Comment: It ***can be*** scoped by request ID – the docs address this directly @user7692855 https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes

Answer (score -2):

use `db.session` like:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def init_app(app):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'your_connection_url_here'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db.init_app(app)
```

```
from flask import Flask
from database import init_app

app = Flask(__name__)
init_app(app)
```

```
from flask import request
from database import db

@app.route('/some_endpoint')
def some_endpoint():
context
    data = db.session.query(SomeModel).filter_by(some_field=request.args.get('param')).all()
    return jsonify(data)
```